# Convert String to date (complex timezone)

Tags: java, string, datetime, jodatime

I have very irregular dates like:

**Mon, 9 Jan 2012 14:18:32 -0800 (GMT)**

**18 Oct 2006 00:32:03 -0000**

**Sat, 18 Nov 2006 19:52:23 UT**

I made a really complex function to get it all done, it works but for the purpose of learning i want to do it again with using try and catch.
My question is, how can i deal with the timezone? You can see all the timezone's in my function, however i also have sometime (... as a timezone for example and i don't want to store all cases in a String array.

Also i want to use [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Freaky_Formatters), (it can be localDate or dateTime, doesn't matter that much to me).

```
public LocalDate handleDate(String date) {

        String[] days = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
        String[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
                "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
        String[] years = { "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009",
                "2010", "2011", "2012" };

        // ORDER IS VERRY IMPORTANT!! ( MEST must be before EST for example)
        String[] timesZones = { "BST", "CET", "CEST", "CST", "CDT", "EDT",
                "GMT+00:00", "GMT", "IST", "MEST", "EST", "MET", "MDT", "PST",
                "PDT", "SAST", "UTC", "UT", "W. Europe Standard Time",
                "West-Europa (zomertijd)" };

        String origDate = date;

        String timeZone = "";
        String year = "";
        String month = "";
        String day = "";
        int hours = 0;
        int minutes = 0;
        int seconds = 0;

        // is it valid?
        date = trim(date);
        if (date.equals("")) {
            return null;
        }

        // first delete the comma that comes mostly after the day
        date = date.replaceAll(",", "");

        // remove the day
        for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
            if (date.contains(days[i])) {
                date = date.replace(days[i], "");
                break;
            }
        }

        // if(date.contains("23:27:17")) println(date);

        for (int i = 0; i < timesZones.length; i++) {
            // first check with '(' and ')'
            String target = "(" + timesZones[i] + ")";

            if (date.contains(target)) {
                timeZone = timesZones[i];
                date = date.replace(target, "");
                break;
            }

            // if not found check without '(' and ')'
            if (date.contains(timesZones[i])) {
                timeZone = timesZones[i];
                date = date.replace(timesZones[i], "");
                break;
            }
        }

        // get the month
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            if (date.contains(months[i])) {
                month = months[i].toLowerCase(); // !must be lowercase
                // must be dutch on my pc
                if (month.equals("oct"))
                    month = "okt";
                if (month.equals("may"))
                    month = "mei";
                if (month.equals("mar"))
                    month = "mrt";

                date = date.replace(months[i], "");
                break;
            }
        }

        // get the year
        for (int i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
            if (date.contains(years[i])) {
                year = years[i];
                date = date.replace(years[i], "");
                break;
            }
        }

        // get the time
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(date);
        if (m.find()) {
            // also fix the time, 00 is not allowed

            hours = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));

            date = date.replaceAll("(\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)", "");
        }

        // get the time difference
        date = date.replace("+-", "+0"); // bug fix where data is incorrect ( 16
                                            // Sep 2007 23:27:17 +-200)

        p = Pattern.compile("[+|-]*(\\d\\d)\\d\\d");
        m = p.matcher(date);
        if (m.find()) {
            int timeDifferenceH = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));

            date = date.replaceAll("([+|-]*\\d\\d\\d\\d)", "");
        }

        date = " " + date; // bug fix

        // get the day
        for (int i = 31; i >= 1; i--) {
            // first check for the ones that contains 2 digits (like 07)
            String d = nf(i, 2);
            if (date.contains(d)) {
                day = nf(i, 2);
                date = date.replace(d, "");
                break;
            }

            // check for 1 digit
            d = "" + i;
            if (date.contains(d)) {
                day = nf(i, 2);
                date = date.replace(d, "");
                break;
            }
        }

        // there should be nothing left except white space
        date = date.replace(" ", "");
        if (date.equals("") == false) {
            println("handleDate: problem with input\n" + date);
            println(origDate + "\n");
            println(year);
            println(month);
            println(day);
        }

        // String cleanDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + nf(hours,
        // 2) + ":" + nf(minutes, 2) + ":" + nf(seconds, 2);
        // DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        // DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        String cleanDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MMM-dd");

        try {

            // DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(cleanDate);
            // LocalDate dt = new LocalDate(cleanDate);
            // return dt.toLocalDate();
            // return dt;
            // return new LocalDate().parse(cleanDate, formatter);
            return formatter.parseLocalDate(cleanDate);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            println("handleDate: Problem with formatting: " + cleanDate);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you aware of things like SimpleDateFormat.parse() and [Apache Commons Validators](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/package-summary.html#date)?

Comment: No magic answers to the problem of various input formats. You just have to try parsing with various formatters until you find one that does not throw an exception. You definitely want to do that in Joda-Time or new java.time in Java 8. The old java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided. To handle various human languages for name of days and months, note the use of java.util.Locale in Joda-Time; no need to hard-code such words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DateTimeFormatter class in JodaTime is quite strong and flexible in this, you should try [Custom Formatters](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Custom_Formatters) or [Freaky Formatters](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Freaky_Formatters)